# Mongoose connected to mongoDB but have not initialized the database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, connection

My connection code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//ES6 Promise
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/smslist", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection
  .once("open", function () {
    console.log("Connected to database successfuly");
  })
  .on("error", function (error) {
    console.log(`DB Connection error:`, error);
  });
```

The mongod server terminal shows that the connection is successfull

```
2020-04-27T15:35:24.500+0300 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:61286 #1 (1 connection now open)
2020-04-27T15:35:24.506+0300 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:61286 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs|Mongoose", version: "3.5.6" }, os: { type: "Windows_NT", name: "win32", architecture: "x64", version: "10.0.18362" }, platform: "'Node.js v12.16.2, LE (unified)", version: "3.5.6|5.9.10" }
```

The node terminal also prints

```
Connected to database successfuly
```

But when I try to use a mongoDB UI like robomongo/studio 3t/mongodb compass community, I will not see a database named smslist as expected.
I also realized that if I close the db server terminal the node terminal still shows connected to database successfully and not `DB Connection error:`, error as expected.

any idea?

Comment: That's probably because you did not create a new document in that database. I doubt if the mongo studios show blank databases. Can you try creating a document inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created any Model yet in this "smslist" database then you can not see any thing about this

You need to create some Model for this "smslist" database then you can see this in your db.

Comment: I have tried to run this code :

const People = require("./peopleSchema");

const saveToDB = function (name, phone) {
  let user = new People({
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
  });
  user.save();
};

saveToDB("terst", "123456");


I still do not see any database

Comment: can you make more clarify?
`

`

Comment: I have imported a model and wrote a code that saves a user named "terst" and the number "123456". Now I'm running this code, "node savetodb.js". No error is shown, but I dont see any database

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd 

You try to add all of these into this file below that is connected mongodb. i think you forget import mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it depends on the code that follows the above.
I've been working through a tutorial on this.

Here is the code and my notes on what finally worked.

```
// from scratch tutorial 
// WORKS!!!!
//require mongoose - works
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

//define constant - works
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruit'

```
// connect to datbase works as evidenced by message
   mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
  const db = mongoose.connection
  db.once('open', _ => {
   console.log('Database connected:', url)
});

db.on('error', err => {
console.error('connection error:', err)
});

//above works!! but do not see new database in mongodb

//now add schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

// define schema
fruitSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 rating: Number,
review: String
});

// create the model - or "collection" use singular - mongoose makes it plural 
  // inside database
   const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

 //now create the document from the model (note upper and lower case)
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Pear",
  rating: 10,
  review: "good with Brie"
});

fruit.save();

  //close the connection works but causes an error when trying to add a document
// mongoose.connection.close();
```